# nullreferenceexception on.. bracket?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@if (Model.LastOrder != null)
{
    <h3>Lorem ipsum:</h3>
}
else
{
    <h3>Lorem lorem!</h3>
} -> here occurs error
```

With this code, I get an error `nullreferenceexception`. Everything could be easy to resolve, but error occurs at... last bracket! Very strange.. and what is more - nothing special is in error info to help me.

Why I get this error?

Here is my controller action:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
     XYZ toReturn = new XYZ { };
     return View(toReturn);
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the LastOrder? Did you check the Model also?

Comment: I got this problem before. Sometimes Razor view reports exception on a line, but actually that exception occurs on the next line of code below. Check if any code below throws an exception.

Comment: Please post the whole view code.